# How to avoid text wrap automatically when useing chakra ui tabs?

Tags: css, reactjs, chakra-ui

I take reference from official document `https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/tabs`

If I just set two `<Tab />`, text is on them same line that is what I want.

```
<Tab>Let text In the same horizontal line</Tab>
<Tab>Two</Tab>
```

But if I set a lot of `<Tab />`, `Let text In the same horizontal line` skip line automatically, I try to set `wordBreak={"unset"}` is not working, how do I fix the issue ?

Here is what I try:

```
<Stack>
      <Tabs position="relative" variant="unstyled">
        <TabList bg="pink" overflowX={"scroll"}>
          <Tab wordBreak={"unset"}>Let text In the same horizontal line</Tab>
          <Tab>Two</Tab>
          <Tab>Three</Tab>
          <Tab>Four</Tab>
          <Tab>Three</Tab>
          <Tab>Five</Tab>
          <Tab>Three</Tab>
          <Tab>Six</Tab>
          <Tab>Three</Tab>
          <Tab>Seven</Tab>
        </TabList>
        <TabIndicator
          mt="-1.5px"
          height="2px"
          bg="blue.500"
          borderRadius="1px"
        />
        <TabPanels>
          <TabPanel>
            <p>one!</p>
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel>
            <p>two!</p>
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel>
            <p>three!</p>
          </TabPanel>
        </TabPanels>
      </Tabs>
    </Stack>
```

Sandbox example:

https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/twk7v6?file=%2Fpackage.json

Comment: your sandbox link is not accessible

Comment: Have you applied CSS styles to the tab labels ? `<TabList style={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}>`. And your sandbox link is broken.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, codesandbox link can be check now.

Comment: @chankruze Thanks you, just type style whiteSpace: 'nowrap' for `<TablList />` is working for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to have all the  elements in the same horizontal line without wrapping to the next line. To achieve this, you can set the CSS whiteSpace property to "nowrap" for the  element. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
<Stack>
  <Tabs position="relative" variant="unstyled">
    <TabList bg="pink" overflowX={"scroll"} style={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}>
      <Tab wordBreak={"unset"}>Let text In the same horizontal line</Tab>
      <Tab>Two</Tab>
      <Tab>Three</Tab>
      <Tab>Four</Tab>
      <Tab>Three</Tab>
      <Tab>Five</Tab>
      <Tab>Three</Tab>
      <Tab>Six</Tab>
      <Tab>Three</Tab>
      <Tab>Seven</Tab>
    </TabList>
    <TabIndicator
      mt="-1.5px"
      height="2px"
      bg="blue.500"
      borderRadius="1px"
    />
    <TabPanels>
      <TabPanel>
        <p>one!</p>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel>
        <p>two!</p>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel>
        <p>three!</p>
      </TabPanel>
    </TabPanels>
  </Tabs>
</Stack>
```